# how to change a string with different variables in mysql db using phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, extjs, replace, phpmyadmin

ok I am redesigning a mobile website, in the older version they used src.sencha.io for their images

reference can be found here: [How to use src.sencha.io](http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/)

Nowadays with CSS it is really pointless, this isn't an app built on the sencha framwork, it's just a plain ol' website. So here's my question, I know you can replace a string in a mysql database with something else, but there's a couple of problems:

A: I'm a bit nervous about trying it, even though I am fanatical about backing everything up (I'll need my noob hand held when being given instructions)and
B: they didn't use the src.sencha.io like this:

```
<img src='http://src.sencha.io/http://DESKTOPwebsite.com/files/u.jpg' alt='My smaller image' />
```

they declared a specific height and width like so:

```
<img src='http://src.sencha.io/320/200/http://DESKTOPwebsite.com/files/u.jpg' alt='My smaller image' />
```

by the look of things, the src.sencha.io is no longer supported anyway because the links to those images are now broken because of it, but that's neither here nor there...my question is this: how do I go into the database and replace http://src.sencha.io/320/200/ with nothing, essentially leaving it blank so the URL for the image just points back to the main site where the files reside? like so:

```
<img src='http://DESKTOPwebsite.com/files/u.jpg' alt='My smaller image' />
```

Keep in mind there are literally hundreds of these images, all with different sizes and widths.  I searched in the database and found so many, that if I were to do it manually it would take me several days to edit each entry one by one.  Is there a way I can replace the the `http://src.sencha.io/number/number/` without specifying the exact height and width?

I hope to goodness I'm making sense to you all, any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table_with_the_urls`
SET your_field_with_url = REPLACE(your_field_with_url,'http://src.sencha.io/320/200/','')
```

[MySQL `REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Sorry, just saw that you have varying widths and heights. Easiest would be to see how many different widths/heights there are run the query multiple times.